# Laravel Relation belongsTo id not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have those schemas:

```
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('ticket_reason_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('ticket_reason_id')->references('id')->on('ticket_reasons')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::create('ticket_reasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And those defined relationships

```
class Ticket extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function reason()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TicketReason::class, 'ticket_reason_id');
    }

}
```

The "reason" method works but I had to manually add the ID. Why do I have to add the id if I'm following the convention? (or at least I think so). It follows the same convention than the user_id column and it doesnt need the id setter.

Comment: It may have to do with the underscore in the table name?

Comment: This is what I thought but I couldnt find anything in the documentation @Sam

Comment: I just read through the documentation quick...can you try renaming your `Ticket` function to `ticket_reason()` and see if it works without specifying the foreign key? If so, I can add this as an answer and link to the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it works. Add the answer. Thanks! @Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm going to fault Laravel's Eloquent documentation on this one...since, it's really not too clear on how the foreign key is auto-generated. I did find this, from the [Eloquent Relationships page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), though (emphasis mine):

> Eloquent will try to match the `user_id` from the `Phone` model to an `id` on the `User` model. Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by ***examining the name of the relationship method*** and suffixing the method name with `_id`.

Contrary to what one (you, myself, etc.) may assume, the foreign key is not generated by the foreign class's name. Instead, it uses the name of the method that your `::belongsTo()` (or `hasOne()`, etc.) call is in.

---

This means that `public function reason() {}` needs to be changed to `public function ticket_reason() {}`. Or, of course, you could change your column name to `reason_id`.